# datatables with bootstrap, buttons and language file not well-formed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to implement language file in this original code from [datatables documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) which shows as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        lengthChange: false,
        buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
    } );
 
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
} );
```

but when i put the language file location the buttons are gone...and i get an error in console: `not well-formed`

How to fix this?

#### update

this is what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Alle"]],
        responsive: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: [ 0, ':visible' ]
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: 'Events export'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                title: 'Events export'

            },
            'colvis',
        ],
        "language": {"url": "/vendor/datatables/german.js"}
    });
 
    table.buttons().container()
        .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );
});
```

Comment: i have updated my question, that is my example where i get that error not well-formed. If i remove the language line all is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
"language": {
       "url" : "js/german.json",
             }
```

with

```
language: {
   "sEmptyTable":      "Keine Daten in der Tabelle vorhanden",
   "sInfo":            "_START_ bis _END_ von _TOTAL_ Einträgen",
   "sInfoEmpty":       "0 bis 0 von 0 Einträgen",
   "sInfoFiltered":    "(gefiltert von _MAX_ Einträgen)",
   "sInfoPostFix":     "",
   "sInfoThousands":   ".",
   "sLengthMenu":      "_MENU_ Einträge anzeigen",
   "sLoadingRecords":  "Wird geladen...",
   "sProcessing":      "Bitte warten...",
   "sSearch":          "Suchen",
   "sZeroRecords":     "Keine Einträge vorhanden.",
   "oPaginate": {
   "sFirst":       "Erste",
   "sPrevious":    "Zurück",
   "sNext":        "Nächste",
   "sLast":        "Letzte"
                },
   "oAria": {
    "sSortAscending":  ": aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
    "sSortDescending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren"
            }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` for `oPaginate` or `language`.   You have two open `{` and only one closing `}`

Comment: Whoops. I copied this from VIM my screen was so big forgot to copy the rest of portion "oAria": {
    "sSortAscending":  ": aktivieren, um Spalte aufsteigend zu sortieren",
    "sSortDescending": ": aktivieren, um Spalte absteigend zu sortieren"
            }. Added that in